# /var/log/tallylogについて

Tags: centos

centos7で/var/log/tallylogが1GB以上使用しています。
これはlogrotate.conf等でローテートする事はできますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

スパースファイルなので、実際の容量はもっと少ない可能性があります。
`ls -ls tallylog` で実際の容量を確認してみると ローテートする必要がない位小さいのではないかと。
lastlog、faillog も同様です。

次の例だと `ls -l` の結果は 498GB ですが、`ls -ls` で実際のサイズを確認すると 44KB しか無いことがわかります。

```
# ls -lhs lastlog
44K -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 498G  2月  1 11:04 lastlog
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/logrotate.conf`はlogrorate全体の設定を行うファイルなので、`tallylog`のログをローテートしたい場合には`etc/logrotate.d/`の下に個別の設定ファイルを用意するほうが良いでしょう。ローテートの頻度などは運用ポリシー次第だと思うので、設定方法は`man logrotate`や`/etc/logrotate.d/`以下にある既存の設定ファイルを参考にするとよいでしょう。

Comment: 返信遅くなりすみませんでした。コメントありがとうございます。tallylogはバイナリ形式でtally2コマンドが内部で参照していると思うのですが、ローテートしても問題ないのでしょうか？